# Label Normalization in Deep Regression Networks

Tags: regression, neural-networks, deep-learning, multilabel

In a typical regression problem there is usually no need for normalizing/rescaling the labels (targets) before performing the optimization.

In deep regression networks there would be in principle no need to rescale since the last activation is linear and the cost function is the euclidean distance of the prediction from the targets.

However, for numerical stability and performance of the training process, the idea is to keep the values of the input and hidden units in the range [-1,1]. Does it mean that also the target of the regression should be rescaled to the [-1,1] range?